# How to bind a static property in a different class to a GridViewColumn of WPF ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

Firstly I am using this for the `ListView` control itself:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding AllEffects}"
```

where 3 `GridViewColumns` already binded to to AllEffects.

But I have 2 more `GridViewColumns` that I want to bind to a separate static property found in:

```
public static class AllSupport
{
    public static EffectSupportLookup<HardwareType, List<EffectSupport>>
}

public class EffectSupport
{
    public bool IsSupported {get;set;}
}
```

I have tried this:

```
<GridViewColumn
    Width="Auto"
    Header="GPU">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox
                Margin="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                IsChecked="{Binding AllSupport, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

But at runtime, it complains that the there is no property called `AllSupport` on `AllEffects`. I don't want to store it inside `AllEffects` because this is a separate class already compatible with the UI, so I just want to bind it to:

```
AllSupport.EffectSupport[GPU].IsSupported
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) Markup Extension.

Something like (never tested):

```
<Window xmlns:local="AssemblyName">
  <ItemsControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:AllSupport.EffectSupport}}" />
</Window>
```

Or thru to a [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx).

**Update**:

1. You have to specify internal path
2. Are you sure the `local` xmlns points to the right clr namespace (get assistance from the VS Xaml Intellisense)
3. Does your app compile before setting it in xaml?
4. Be more specific with your generic class implmenetation, what are you trying to achieve? is it a dictionary? a generic class? please reedit your code to give us the right look of your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But where do I have to specify to use the IsSupported property for the binding?

Comment: When I use this it says local:AllSupport not found but it's global in the same assembly so accessibly.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it. Although it still complains not finding local:AllSupport.

Comment: @Shimmy, thanks, just saw your edit.  I have it setup like this: i55.tinypic.com/1hfm7l.png The blue rectangles show the VM items which has 3 property that fill the columns. But the green ones is coming from the static class that fill the rows, since their order is synced. If ItemsSource means 1 collection, can I not use it and bind each GridViewColumn to a different collection. There must be a way to do that at least.

Comment: As for your questions. 1. Can you show the Path example in your sample? 2. Sorry I didn't notice your xmlns:local code, now I set it correctly and it finds it in code. 3. The app complies successfully before and after. 4. Reposting the link: http://i55.tinypic.com/1hfm7l.png, continued in the next comment.

Comment: So if you look at the image I posted in the previous comment, you can see that blue rectangles indicate ViewModel objects that have 3 properties. But the static class I have has a dictionary where the dictionary has a List of EffectSupport for every HardwareType supported. So if I have effects shown in this ListView, they would appear as A, B, C, D, where each one has a Name, Type, etc. But the static class' dictionary stores their support like this: For GPU: true, true, false, false for A, B, C, D respectively. For CPU, similar style.

Comment: So I want to bind my static class' dictionary, where there is a List for each GridViewColumn with EffectSupport values that have a property called .IsSupported.

Answer (score 2):

> I have 2 more GridViewColumns that I want to bind to a separate static property

I don't think you can do that, 1 ItemsSource means 1 SourceCollection.

But you can easily use LINQ to create a ad-hoc collection that includes those 2 columns

> I don't want to store it inside AllEffects because this is a separate class already compatible with the UI,

If this means it's a ViewModel class, and if you want those columns in the View, then that is a very strong reason they **should** be stored in that class. Or in a separate, derived, ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks I have it setup like this: http://i55.tinypic.com/1hfm7l.png The blue rectangles show the VM items which has 3 property that fill the columns. But the green ones is coming from the static class that fill the rows, since their order is synced. If ItemsSource means 1 collection, can I not use it and bind each GridViewColumn to a different collection. There must be a way to do that at least.